# My 33 months old calls me by her name

Tags: toddler, infant, pre-schooler, names

My toddler calls me her name. Has anyone else child ever done this. I keep telling her that is her name.

Comment: I have seen a kid call is mother "aunt" because that was the name his cousin used. Or "darling" because that was the name the father used. I have also been called "papa" by a child I did not even know. Just ask her "who am i"? or something.

Answer (score 2):

A toddler tends to repeat what her or his parents tell the opposite. So, I think that whenever she calls you her name, you just persistently say the correct thing, that is, your name. You should do it over and over, and eventually it will pay off.

In my case, my dear son kept calling the pillow is the "people" although he was aware that it was wrong, but he just called it such name since he found it easy to remember or for some similar reasons. My spouse and his grandparents asked him to call it by the correct name, but he just ignored. However, whenever my son said "people" for pillow, I raised my eyebrows and asked him "Do you want pillow?", or "You want people? They are outside the street". Finally, he says pillow instead of people.